# Output voltage function (circuit-analysis)

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, function

What will the function of the output voltage be?

[image]

My work, and am I right?:

$$\text{V}_{\text{out}}(t)=\frac{\text{R}_9\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)}{\text{R}_{10}}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_{11}\text{C}_1}\int\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)\space\text{d}t+\text{R}_{12}\text{C}_2\cdot\frac{\partial\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)}{\partial t}$$

Comment: It's a PID block - what more to say?

Comment: Yes it is, but is my output voltage function right?

Comment: how have you accounted for the gain due to op amps 1 and 2?

Comment: No the gain isn't one, I named it number 1

Comment: The gain is 0.75 by the look of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so op amps 3, 4 and 5 form a PID block. Considering their respective output voltages as Vp, Vi and Vd:

$$ V_p = -\frac{R_9}{R_{10}}V_{in} $$

$$ V_i = -\frac{1}{R_{11}C_{1}}\int{V_{in}dt} $$

$$ V_d = -R_{12}C_2\frac{dV_{in}}{dt} $$

Op amp 2 and resistors R3-8 are used to sum these voltages. Using superposition, one can solve this block's output (Vx). Let's say Vi and Vd are 0; R5, R7 and R8 are then in parallel and the voltage on the op amp '+' will be Vp/4.

$$ V_{x(V_p)} = \left(\frac{R_3}{R_4} + 1\right)\frac{V_p}{4} = 0.75V_p$$

Therefore, with superposition, Vx is 0.75(Vp + Vi + Vd). The last op amp is just a regular negative gain circuit, and Vout = -Vx. Final answer:

$$ V_{out} = 0.75\left(\frac{R_9}{R_{10}}V_{in} + \frac{1}{R_{11}C_{1}}\int{V_{in}dt} + R_{12}C_2\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}\right)$$

Comment: Why the 0.75? Because Vi and Vd aren't 0

Comment: Superposition is an analysis tool for linear circuits. It takes the basic property of a linear operator L: L(a+b+c) = L(a) + L(b) + L(c). Considering the circut "simmetry" between different inputs, when one solves for L(a) (special case when b and c are 0), there will be a similar answer for L(b) and L(c), and the final result will be the sum of such answers.

Comment: Oh yes I understand, but is there a way to make it 1, I've to change the value of the resistors but how?

Comment: (1 + R3/R4) should result in 4, not 3. R3 could be 30k, for example.

Comment: So, if I make R3 30k than it will be the ouput function that I supposed in my question?!

Comment: yup, (1 + R3/R4) would cancel the dividing coefficient, 4

Comment: But do my instinct say that if I change R3 than we have to change also R5-R8 or isn't that right?

Comment: No, but R5 to R8 do form a resistive division; keeping them the way they are right now and aiming for gain 1, changing R3 to 30k solves the issue directly. When in doubt, do the "slow" maths. If you need more help we should move to chat.